# Image Capture activity won't return

Tags: android

I'm trying to build an activity that takes a picture on a button click event. Below is the code I use to start the Image Capture activity:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    fotoFile = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(fotoFile);
    Intent intentNovaFoto = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intentNovaFoto.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
    startActivityForResult(intentNovaFoto, 0);
}
```

The Image Capture activity starts, I'm able to take the picture, but when I click the little check button to accept the image, nothing happens. My app's manifest file contains the appropriate use-permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Any hints on what I am missing?

Thanks!

**Edit:**

This app has an activity which contains two fragments; I am creating and starting the Intent in one of those fragments. It works as expected if I replace the line `startActivityForResult(intentNovaFoto, 0);` by `getActivity().startActivityForResult(intentNovaFoto, 0);`. The issue is that I'd like to start the activity on the fragment and have the onActivityResult called on the fragment; is that possible at all?

Comment: What do you mean nothing happens? Doesn't the last activity is back to front?

Comment: The button seems to be unresponsive. I click it and nothing happens. However, if I start the intent from the parent activity, it works (ie, the confirm button works as expected, returning to the previous activity).

Comment: Do you have the `onActivityResult` implemented?

Comment: For documentation purposes, the issue was that the file I was (erroneously) creating was not getting written. So, if you ever run into a similar issue, pay attention to that : )